# Delete first 2 rows of multiple csv files with python

Tags: python, csv, delete-row

I have a directory (with several subfolders) of csv files. I want to delete the first 2 rows of all csv files before I upload the csv files to a database (SQL server). I started with the following python script on a small subset of csv files located in one folder (no sub folders) and although the script runs successfully but no rows are deleted from the files. What am I missing:

```
import glob
import csv

myfiles = glob.glob("C:\Data\*.csv")
for file in myfiles:
    lines = open(file).readlines()
    open(file, 'w').writelines(lines[1:])
```

Here is my sample data:

```
"Title: Distribution of Nonelderly Population by Household Employment Status | The Henry J. Kaiser Family Foundation"
"Timeframe: 2015"
"Location","At Least 1 Full Time Worker","Part Time Workers","Non Workers","Total"
"United States","0.82","0.08","0.10","1.00"
"Alabama","0.79","0.06","0.15","1.00"
"Alaska","0.85","0.06","0.09","1.00"
"Arizona","0.80","0.08","0.12","1.00"
"Arkansas","0.78","0.07","0.15","1.00"
"California","0.81","0.08","0.10","1.00"
```

I want to maintain the same directory structure with the edited output csv files. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So, what's the question? What problems did you run into?

Comment: I tried on a small subset of csv files in one folder (no subfolders) and the above script although runs successfully but doesn't delete any row.

Comment: shouldn't you close the file before opening it in write mode?

Comment: Describe your actual problem in your question, not the comments. You probably also want to look at `os.walk`

Comment: if all his csv files are in the same flat directory, no need to use os.walk

Comment: @Arepo question talks about 'directory structure'.

Comment: oh yes, but not in his sample directory, otherwise glob can also take wildcards for the structure, as long as it's an easy one of course, otherwise os.walk is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

# Change this to your CSV file base directory
base_directory = 'C:\\Data'    
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a CSV file
        if not file_name.endswith('.csv'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'r') as ifile:
            line_list = ifile.readlines()
        with open(file_path, 'w') as ofile:
            ofile.writelines(line_list[2:])
```

**Note:** DO NOT use file as a variable name or you will clobber the built-in class.

Comment: No luck with the above

Comment: I updated the answer to handle an arbitrary directory structure using `os.walk`.